# How to replace certain characters in a string?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I'm trying to work a way around a problem and need a solution (Ok - I'm probably going to get negative rep) but here goes:

Let's assume I have the following:

```
Actual: A B D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Z 
Change: X F S M E P U T V L Q H K I J W A D O R Z B G N
```

And, basically, I want to replace all characters in a string which are contained in the "Actual" list, with the respective characters from the "Change" list. If some character is not in the "Actual" list, it must stay unchanged.

I have attempted to do it, but, it does not work:

```
foreach (var c in charList) {
    if (input.Contains (c.Key)) {
        foreach (var a in charList) {
            decrypted[i] = a.Key;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

I basically just get the "N" value.. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You are using the same string

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243669/how-do-i-perform-several-string-replacements-in-one-go

Comment: @Nile, wouldn't exactly say it's a duplicate but ok. And updated. Oh, I get negative feedback.. Wow

Answer (score 4):

My improvisation:

1.At first create a dictionary

```
        List<char> Actual = "A B D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Z".Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s[0]).ToList();
        List<char> Change = "X F S M E P U T V L Q H K I J W A D O R Z B G N".Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s[0]).ToList();
        Dictionary<char, char> ReplacemetRules = Actual.ToDictionary(s => s, s => Change[Actual.IndexOf(s)]);
```

or just

```
Dictionary<char, char> ReplacemetRules = new Dictionary<char, char>
        {
            {'T','F'},
            {'E','A'},
            {'S','Q'}
        };
```

2.Say we have an input string:

```
     string input = "TEST";
```

then just use:

```
        string output = string.Concat(input.Select(c => ReplacemetRules.ContainsKey(c) ? ReplacemetRules[c] : c)));
```

Comment: Hey @horgh so your approach is to replace the Actual, to Change and then replace all the characters inside the string?

Comment: The characters aren't actually replaced. The original string stays unchanged. But a new string is created and (in the example) returned into the `output` variable.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with Linq, it may be difficult to understand how it works. Actually it uses each char in the input string, searching such key in the dictionary and returns the value from the dictionary (if the key is present there) or the input character itself, if the dictionary is missing that key

Comment: So, `input.Select(..` generates an array of characters (actually `IEnumerable<char>`), which are used to combine an output string by `string.Concat` method

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this when I get home @horgh I'm trying to decrypt some data based on letter frequencies

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
        string InputString = "TEST";
        string EncryptedString = string.Empty;
        string IfContains =  "ABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZ";
        string ReplaceWith = "XFSMEPUTVLQHKIJWADORZBGN";

        foreach (char InputChar in InputString)
        {
            int IndexToReplace = IfContains.IndexOf(InputChar);

            if (IndexToReplace >= 0)
            {
                EncryptedString = string.Concat(EncryptedString, ReplaceWith[IndexToReplace]);
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE**: you should take care with case. Performing a case-insensitive search would be a better idea.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.. It seems I cannot use IfContains.. foreach (var InputChar in input) {
    int IndexToReplace = IfContains.IndexOf(InputChar);
   }

Comment: @Phorce Sorry, I didn't understand. Isn't it working for you?

Comment: Nope, 'The name 'IfContains' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Phorce Dude, have you copied the **whole** code? I declare 4 strings before the loop, they are *required*.

Comment: Hey, but "IfContains" is a list, and "ReplaceWith" is a Dictionary.. And I get an error in the int IndexToReplace saying the best overload method .. Cannot convert char to KeyPairValue<char, double> any ideas @Andre Calil?

Comment: **Why** aren't they `strings`? They should be of the same type, because you must use the index to make the exchange.

Comment: I have converted them: http://pastebin.com/eUpjCGXN both are strings, I still get the same error.. Sorry for bad coding, C# isn't my native language

Comment: Look at lines 87 and 88. Calling `ToString()` won't affect the calling object. It **returns a string**, you must assign it to another variable.

Comment: Nahh, that did not work! just produced.. GIGVIPIKGVGGG,GGILIIIGSGKVKGIG.GILKGIGLIG,IVLIGLIG,LPVKIIKVK.IVGGLVILPGSGGLGVKKILGIGIGI,K,KLG,IGGGGIGGG.V,GGKKILGKGIKIVKVPGKLGVPI,GGPIGGGPPLKGLIGIVG. lol

Comment: Dude, I give up. Don't wtf you're doing, but if you simply copy the above code and try it you'll see that it works. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var c in charList) {
    if (input.Contains (c.Key)) {
        foreach (var a in charList) {
            decrypted[i] = a.Key;
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```