# C# Replace with mixed values

Tags: c#, php

What I am looking for is a way to replicate `PHP str_replace()` function in `C#`.

In `PHP` code It would look like:

```
$string = 'This is my demo y string!';
$search_for = array("y","x","z");
$replace_with = array("1","2","3");
if( str_replace($search_for,$replace_with,$string) ) {
    $changed = true;
};
```

Where the `y` is changed to `1`, `x` changed to `2` etc., And if anything was changed then set the variable `changed` or do any other code.

How to do the same in `C#`?
Thank you.

Comment: You can't do that in one `string.Replace`, you will need three different calls to `string.Replace` in C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I perform several string replacements in one go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243669/how-do-i-perform-several-string-replacements-in-one-go)

Comment: @Habib ok, but can I use `string.Replace` with `if`? Like: `if(string.Replace('a','b')) {};` ?

Comment: You'd do `if (string.Contains("x")) { // ... }`

Comment: @wzazza, no, C# `if` expects a boolean parameter or a statement which results in bool, `string.Replace` would return a string, thus it will fail.

Comment: You would have to do something like: `if(string.Replace("","").Compare(string) != 0){}` to check if it did change.

Comment: I don't agree the question is a duplicate. The answer may be, but the question is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain your string replaces like so:

```
var result = myString.Replace("y", "1").Replace("x", "2").Replace("z", "3");
```

That should do what you are looking for. An alternative approach if you had arrays with the replacements would be:

```
var originalChar = new List<char> { '1', '2', '3' };
var replaceWith = new List<char> { 'x', 'y', 'z' };
originalChar.ForEach(x => myString = myString.Replace(x, replaceWith[originalChar.IndexOf(x)]));
```

This could probably be more efficient but you get the idea.

**Checking for a change:**

As noted in the comments, checking for a change is as simple as checking if the original and the modified string are no longer equal:

```
var changed = (result != myString);
```

Comment: `var changed = result != myString`

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I did end up using `string.Replace("y","1").Replace("x","2")..` and then comparing changed string to original one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `LINQ` and a `Dictionary`

```
var mappings = new Dictionary<char,char> { {'y', '1' }, { 'x', '2'} , {'z','3'}};

var newChars = inputString
                     .Select(x =>
                     {
                         if (mappings.ContainsKey(x)) 
                                return mappings[x];
                         return x;
                     })
                     .ToArray();

var output = new string(newChars);

bool changed = !(output == inputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward port, although I think it would be better to use C# the "conventional" way.

```
string inputString = "This is my demoy y string!";
string[] searchFor = new string[] { "y", "x", "z" }; // or char[] if you prefer
string[] replaceWith = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
if (ArrayReplace(searchFor, replaceWith, ref inputString))
{
    bool changed = true;
}

bool ArrayReplace(string[] searchFor, string[] replaceWith, ref string inputString) 
{
    string copy = inputString;
    for (int i = 0; i < searchFor.Length && i < replaceWith.Length; i++) 
    {
        inputString = inputString.Replace(searchFor[i], replaceWith[i]);       
    }
    return copy != inputString;
}
```